Batching of Credit Note allocations in the Xero API
We have a system that will processing daily Invoices (~1) and Credit Notes (1 or 2) for several thousand Contacts. We have no problem creating these using the API as all items can be batched into one call, but if we need to allocate each credit note individually we are going to go over our API rate limits. Is there a way to batch these allocations (or better yet do the allocation when creating the Credit Note)?
I tested adding allocations when creating approved Credit Notes via the API but the allocations were ignored.

If you are creating thousands of credit notes per day you may be at the limit of the recommended usage of Xero and you may need to handle the credit notes outside of Xero; just send summary accouting information to Xero.
Xero Developer Centre: Suggested limits
